# My sub-query returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql

Of course, the problem is that I'm getting more rows in the sub-query.

But I don't know how to fix it in order to achieve my goals.

This is how my query looks like:

```
SELECT movies.name, movies.id, 
    (SELECT username FROM users INNER JOIN movies ON 
        movies.added_by_id = users.id) 
    AS added_by_username FROM movies
```

For example we have more movies in our db, and those movies were added by users.

**GOALS:** I want to display all the movies and the usernames of the users who added them.

Comment: Do you have any example output? What did you expect the query to return, and what does it return instead?

Comment: typically, when you want to get fewer rows from your subquery, you'll use distinct or group by, but for what you're doing (returning one row per movie/user pair,) you don't need the subquery at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for a subquery:

```
SELECT movies.name, movies.id, username 
FROM users 
  INNER JOIN movies 
    ON movies.added_by_id = users.id
```

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR - Sure, but do you understand _why_ it does and why a subquery is not needed?

Comment: Because we need to call the db only once. A kind of that.

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR - I know she explained. But if you don't quite understand what she meant and why it works, you are just programming without understanding.

Comment: I understood how it works, thank you! I knew that there is a way to do it without sub-query, but I were doing it too complex.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT movies.name, movies.id, 
(SELECT TOP 1 username FROM users INNER JOIN movies ON 
    movies.added_by_id = users.id) 
AS added_by_username FROM movies
```